# How do I get the yaml definition of a pod that failed to create?

Tags: kubernetes

I get the following event in K8s:

```
FailedCreate  statefulset/my-pod    create Pod my-pod in StatefulSet my-pod failed error: Pod "my-pod" is invalid: spec.containers[0].volumeMounts[5].mountPath: Invalid value: "/path/to/folder": must be unique
```

How do I get the `yaml` definition of `my-pod`? We have multiple webhooks and I have no idea what the final yaml definition actually looks like

Comment: I am looking forward to your feedback to understand whether the provided resolution has helped you in resolving the issue. If not, I am happy to assist further.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this command to get the `yaml` definition of pod:

```
kubectl get pod pod-name -n namespace-name -o yaml
```

But I think in your case event clearly shows the error, you need to check path "/path/to/folder".

Answer (score 0):

You can get yaml definition of the pod by using kubectl , try below command

```
kubectl get pod my-pod -o yaml
```

Above command is used to provide detailed information about a specific pod in YAML format.

You can find more information in the [blog](https://www.baeldung.com/ops/kubernetes-yaml-deployed-object) authored by Narendra Kangralkar, Check this [cheat sheet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#:%7E:text=kubectl%20get%20pod%20my%2Dpod%20%2Do%20yaml) for more commands.

I have replicated it,command is working for both the scenarios i.e., pods with error and not.

[image]

Above image gives the output of yaml with a failed or error state.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is review the statefulset that manage the pod creation.

```
kubectl get sts my-pod
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is very clear from the error message `must be unique` is a storage error that occurs when you try to mount multiple source volumes to the same destination path within your container specification.

Use the kubectl command to see the stateful set specification
kubectl get sts my-pod -o yaml

Please check each mountPath and make sure there are no duplicates.